# Android Facebook Logout: Where can I make code run when this happens?

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I followed multiple tutorials and have been able to create my Android app with Facebook Login with the newest SDK (4.1.2). Login and log out both work fine.

The issue I'm having is everywhere I search, I am unable to figure out what code is run when I click the logout button, and where I can write code I want executed after the user logs out.

Most answers I find for monitoring this involve the Session class which is no longer included in the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For facebook sdk 4.0+ you have to use LoginManager class to logout. Place your own logout button  wherever you want and call 

LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
//activity to start